# Do there exist any three relatively prime natural numbers so that the square of each of them is divisible by the sum of the two remaining numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, diophantine-equations

$\textbf{Question:}$Do there exist any three relatively prime natural numbers so that the square of each of them is divisible by the sum of the two remaining numbers?

that is pairwise  relatively prime $a,b,c \in \mathbb N  $($0$ not included) such that $a+b \mid c^2,b+c \mid a^2,c+a \mid b^2$

$\textbf{Stuffs I have tried:}$
I have tried a bunch of constructions like :$(p,\frac{p+1}{2},\frac{p-1}{2})$,one of them are the sum of other two,tried small values.But was unable to find any valid triple.So,I began trying to prove such triple can't exist.I tried to bound the numbers,tried to use modular arithmatic but failed again.

Any kind of hint or solution will both be appreciated.

Comment: There is no solution with $1\le a\le b\le c\le 2\ 000$. But I only used brute force with pari/gp.

Comment: What might help : It is easy to show that exactly one of the numbers must be even.

Comment: There are plenty of solutions which are **not** coprime. This certainly hints at something; not sure what exactly, though.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin can you give an example of a solution where $a,b,c$ not coprime? Many thanks!

Comment: (3,3,6), (10,20,30), and many in between...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's see. So we have
$$\begin{cases}
a^2 = x(b+c) \\
b^2 = y(a+c) \\
c^2 = z(a+b)
\end{cases}$$
where all quantities are integers. What does this mean?

For one thing, each of $a,b,c$ is strictly greater than 1.

For another, if $a,b,c$ are all pairwise coprime (as per the problem statement), then so are $b+c, a+c, a+b$.

Now let's make one peculiar combination out of these numbers, for no reason at all:

$$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+2ab+2ac+(b+c)^2=x(b+c)+2a(b+c)+(b+c)^2$$

So it is divisible by $b+c$, and also (following similar reasoning) by $a+b$ and $a+c$. If these three are all mutually coprime, then it is divisible by their **product**.

Assume that $a<b<c$. Then $b+c>{2\over3}(a+b+c)$ and $a+c>{1\over3}(a+b+c)$. So...

$$(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)\;|\;(a+b+c)^2\\
(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)\leqslant(a+b+c)^2\\
(a+b)\cdot{1\over3}(a+b+c)\cdot{2\over3}(a+b+c)<(a+b+c)^2\\
a+b < {9\over2}\\
a+b \leqslant 4$$

With $a,b>1$ this only leaves us the option of $a=b=2$, which are not coprime.

Finally, there are no such coprime triples. Q.e.d.

Comment: Very beautiful answer! I do have some comments though....I believe it says $a,b,c$ not sharing a factor, this can be made $a,b,c$ pairwise coprime by observing that if $a$ and $b$ share a prime factor then so must $c$, and so indeed $a,b,c$ must be pairwise coprime...and so must $a^2,b^2,c^2$, and therefore, so must $(c+b), (a+c), (a+b)$, because $c+b | a^2$ etc... This is actually nitpicking on my part though.

Comment: Yes, probably I should have mentioned that "collectively coprime" and "pairwise coprime" mean the same thing here.

Comment: You can't assume that the sums are coprime. E.g. with $a=2, b = 3, c = 13$, we have $ a+b = 5, a + c = 15$.

Comment: Ah, but you could say that $ \gcd ( a+b, b+c ) \leq \gcd (c^2, a^2) = 1$, after which the rest of the proof holds.

Comment: Yes I can assume that the sums are coprime, for they are the divisors of squares, which are coprime.

Comment: I do believe you have to make that logic more explicit, especially in a contest math setting.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

1. Clearly $ a > 1, b > 1 , c > 1$.
2. WLOG $ a < b < c$
3. $ 0 \equiv c^2 \equiv c(c+a+b) \equiv (a+b+c)(a+b+c) \pmod{a+b}$ (and similar expressions)
4. $\gcd(a+b, b+c ) \mid \gcd( c^2, a^2) = 1$  so $\gcd(a+b, b+c) = 1$. (and similar expressions)

Hence
$$ (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \mid (a+b+c)^2 \Rightarrow (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \leq (a+b+c)^2. $$

Thus

$$ 4 (a+b)( b+c)^2 < 4 (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \leq \left[2(a+b+c)\right]^2 < [3(b+c)]^2$$

which implies that $ (a+b) < \frac{ 9}{4} $, which is a contradiction.